# Copy entire commit into a separate directory

Tags: bash, git

I am trying to write some end-to-end tests for my lab's codebase. My initial idea was to iterate through every commit on `master` (i.e. every version of the program)

```
for commit in $(git rev-list master | head)
do
  rm -rf build
  git checkout -b "${commit}" ${commit}
  #do tests, etc.
done
```

but this method gets pretty messy when I start moving files between different branches. My new idea is to copy the contents of each separate version (commit) into a separate directory, such that the directory structure would look like

```
all_versions/                                                                                         │
├── commit_0                                                                                          │
├── commit_1                                                                                          │
└── commit_2
```

**Is there a `git` command that I can use to cleanly copy the contents of an entire commit into a directory?**

Comment: Git doesn't provide an export command that produces a directory but it provides [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) that outputs a `tar` archive. Its output can be piped to `tar -x` that restores the files and the directory structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Git doesn't provide an export command that produces a directory but it provides [`git archive`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive) that outputs a `tar` archive. Its output can be piped to `tar -x` that restores the files and the directory structure.

Assuming you have already computed the output directory (`commit_0`, `commit_1` etc. in your example) into the variable `dir`, the command is:

```
git archive $commit --prefix="$dir/" | tar x -C all_versions
```

Comment: This almost works, but the output directory is empty.

Comment: It works fine for me, I tested it before posting the answer. The `all_versions` directory must exist (and you better put an absolute path there), the subdirectory whose name is stored in `$dir` does not need to exist, the `/` after `$dir` is required. If `$dir` contains spaces then use `--prefix="$dir/"` (I updated it in the answer too). Of course, you have to be sure that `$commit` is a valid commit reference (branch name or hash).

Comment: Ah, I found the error I was making. Thank you so much!